# Backup linux system skipping particular folders and files

Tags: linux, backup, system-restore, system-backup

I have install a lubuntu system fully functional in my sister's laptop.
Now, I want to take a backup of system without specific files and folders like "~/movies" "~/music" etc because I backup these files in other place, live.

Clonezilla does not support this.

Is there another low level method?
e.g. boot from USB stick, making some TAR thing and then XZ compression?

I prefer non-low-level but number of options decreases (currently is zero).

I don't care for automatic partition creation. I only care for a restoration of system and all installed packages and all system settings and all per-user settings super-fast.

If TAR can do this, can also keep ACL records? (this is just spice)

Answer (score 0):

Whow. A little search in google give me this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR
Lets try it.